# How to call a method within fbDialogNotLogin?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK in my app, but need help with what happens when the login process is cancelled. I tried referencing another controller, but it crashes and I get an error of `Instance variable 'textview_facebook' accessed in a class method`.

It looks like I cannot make graphical changes inside this kind of method... how can I get around this?

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Facebook.m

```
- (void)fbDialogNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
  if ([self.sessionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fbDidNotLogin:)]) {
    [_sessionDelegate fbDidNotLogin:cancelled];
      NSLog(@"Facebook Cancelled!!!");
      [MapViewController stuffIsCancelled];
  }
}
```

MapViewController.m

```
  +(void)stuffIsCancelled {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

        textview_facebook.alpha = 0;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the method not found? Is the stuffIsCanceled method defined in MapViewController.h also?

Comment: I wrote the wrong warning... it actually says `Instance variable 'textview_facebook' accessed in a class method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are in a class method you cannot access the instance properties, you only have access to static variables.

Depending on your project structure you can:

- Set the session delegate to be the `MapViewController` assuming that
  you call the login from it, implement the `fbDidNotLogin`
  method and move the animations stuff in it.
- Make the `MapViewController` a singleton and make the `stuffIsCanceled`
  an object method.
- Make the `textview_facebook` static

Comment: Hi Alin, thanks for your help! I must admit, I'm pretty new to all of this.. which path would you recommend?